# static_transform_publisher base_link base_laser

Tags: ros, static-transform-publisher, base-link, base-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone

Is this line enough in order to use tf package for set  a fixed relation between base_link and base_laser frames in my launch file?

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link base_laser 100" />
```

and do i need other nodes or scripts to set /map frames or others especially when we want to use packages like gmapping or amcl??
thanks:))))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192713/static_transform_publisher-base_link-base_laser/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-09-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is this line enough in order to use tf package for set a fixed relation between base_link and base_laser frames in my launch file?

Yes, if you want them to have an identity transform inbetween them (0 0 0 0 0 0).

> do i need other nodes or scripts to set /map frames or others especially when we want to use packages like gmapping or amcl?

For `gmapping` and `amcl`, which both publish the `map->odom` transform, you want to make sure you already provide an accurate `odom->base_link` transform, as well as publishing odometry to the `odom` topic. [More info here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom).

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2